# trait Build in package sbt is deprecated: Use .sbt format instead

Tags: scala, sbt

Using sbt 0.13.5, when opening the project in IntelliJ, there is a warning message

> ~\myproject\project\Build.scala:5: trait Build in package sbt is
>   deprecated: Use .sbt format instead

The content of the Build.scala is

```
import sbt._
object MyBuild extends Build  {
  lazy val root = Project("MyProject", file("."))
    .configs(Configs.all: _*)
    .settings(Testing.settings ++ Docs.settings: _*)
}
```

The [Appendix: .scala build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Full-Def.html) and the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html) is rather overwhelming.

How to merge my existing Build.scala to build.sbt? Would appreciate any direction to doc/tutorial/examples.

Comment: you will have to just move the content of MyBuild to an sbt file (build.sbt is the convention)

Comment: tried that, got confused by syntax. The Build.scala I tried to convert doesn't have the Key := Value structure as seen in the example shown in the sbt doc.

Comment: You should be using sbt 0.13.13.

Comment: @SethTisue Just went ahead and upgraded to 0.13.13. All tests passed. Now just need to learn how to migrate the build.scala mentioned above into build.sbt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename `Build.scala` to `build.sbt` and move it up one directory level, so it's at the top rather than inside the `project` directory.

Then strip out the beginning and end, leaving:

```
lazy val root = Project("MyProject", file("."))
  .configs(Configs.all: _*)
  .settings(Testing.settings ++ Docs.settings: _*)
```

That's the basics.

Then if you want to add more settings, for example:

```
lazy val root = Project("MyProject", file("."))
  .configs(Configs.all: _*)
  .settings(
    Testing.settings,
    Docs.settings,
    name := "MyApp",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )
```

You don't need the `:_*` thing on sequences of settings anymore in sbt 0.13.13; older versions required it.

The migration guide in the official doc is here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html#Migrating+from+the+Build+trait

Comment: Works perfect! There is actually a build.sbt, I just deleted the old project/Build.scala and moved that chunk of code in the top of build.sbt. There are still a lot of 1 line setting (with a blank line between each) in our build.sbt. I attempted to follow the [Build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html#What+is+a+build+definition%3F) by adding some more keys. `name := "MyApp" , scalaVersion = "2.11.8"` inside `.settings(...)`. But got error **sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression. no `: _*' annotation allowed here** Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: If `:_*` is no longer need, is it OK to change `.configs(Configs.all: _*)` to `.configs(Configs.all)`? Also should I move all the single line settings currently in build.sbt inside the `.settings(etc.)`. Example: `parallelExecution in Test := false`, `javacOptions  ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")`. More exactly, what is the recommended location to define a setting? When inside `.setting()` and when as single line in build.sbt?

Comment: BTW, what is the difference of the name used in `Project("MyProject"` and the setting key `name := "MyApp"` ? Where are these `names` used? In the SBT API, [Project.id](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.Project) says `id = "My Project"` is "The project ID is used to uniquely identify a project within a build." However, there is no description related to [Keys.name](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.Keys$)

Comment: These are good questions, but I think I've answered your original question — I'd suggest opening new questions.