# Guidelines for a modern build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

This is kind of an extension of a former question
[trait Build in package sbt is deprecated: Use .sbt format instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488840/trait-build-in-package-sbt-is-deprecated-use-sbt-format-instead)

What is the recommended guidelines to cleanup build.sbt to bring it up to date with the latest sbt 0.13.13 (as of March 2017). Example:

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "MyProject", file("."))
  .configs(Configs.all: _*)
  .settings(
    Testing.settings,
    Docs.settings,
    name := "MyApp",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  )

parallelExecution in Test := false
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-Xlint:-missing-interpolator", "-Xfatal-warnings", "-Xlint")

assemblySettings
test in assembly := {}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
  etc.
)

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4444",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
  "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
)

// settings values for addSbtPlugin("org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "4.0.1")
flywayUrl      := "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydbname"
flywayUser     := "someone"
flywayPassword := "****"
```

**Q1.** 
Should `.configs(Configs.all: _*)` be changed to `.configs(Configs.all)` ?

**Q2.** What are the items worth to be placed inside `.settings(...)`. And the opposite, when should something be placed in the body of build.sbt?

**Q3.** what is the difference of the name used in `Project(id = "MyProject", ..)` and the setting key `name := "MyApp"` ? Where are these names used? In the SBT API, [Project.id](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.Project) says id = "My Project" is "The project ID is used to uniquely identify a project within a build." However, there is no description related to [Keys.name](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/#sbt.Keys%24)

**Q4.** Any thing which should be simplified/changed from the example above? For example, is it OK to place the settings of the various plugins there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not a definitive guideline (I doubt one could point to such a thing), but some answers.

1. signature of (old) `configs` is:

   ```
   def configs(cs: Configuration*): Project
   ```

   It means it accepts varargs as a parameter - `Configs.all: _*` is a valid way to pass `Seq` as sequence of varargs arguments. If you are on SBT.0.13.13 you can change it if you like, on older versions it will break.
2. if you are using root project:

   ```
   lazy val root = Project(id = "MyProject", file("."))
   ```

   settings you put in `root.settings()` are virtually the same as settings you put in `build.sbt` directly. The former is actually more useful when you have multiple modules/subprojects:

   ```
   lazy val root = Project(id = "MyProject", file("."))
      .aggregate(a, b)

   lazy val a = Project(id = "A", file("modules/a"))
      .settings()

   lazy val b = Project(id = "B", file("modules/b"))
      .settings()
   ```

   Personally I would use `.settings`-only approach for everything in multimodule project (for consistency) and all directly in `build.sbt` in a single module project.
3. when you are building (Maven, Ivy) artifact you generate it for 3 names creating a namespaces: an organization, a name and a version. Unless you change it name is copied from id. Id itself is something that decides on your project name when you run sbt (`you are in project root`) which makes more of a difference when you have multiple modules. Using:

   ```
   lazy val root = (project in file("."))
   ```

   will make use of macro that would take the variable name and use it as project's id - so something equal to:

   ```
   lazy val root = Project(id = "root", file("."))
   ```
4. values from `settings` can be moved outside:

   ```
   Testing.settings
   Docs.settings
   name := "MyApp"
   scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
   ```

   unless you are using some nonstandard configs you should get away without `.configs()`. It would be hard to use `Configs.all` directly in `build.sbt`, but if it won't be needed, then you could drop

   ```
   lazy val root = Project(id = "MyProject", file("."))
   ```

   altogether as all settings applied to `build.sbt` are applied to project in the same directory (`.`).

As far as I can tell, if it's not deprecated, it is a matter of taste. Try to simply apply some common sense and good practices in general - after all it is just a code.

Comment: I wish the SBT team include your explanations in the documentation [Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html).   How about naming convention regarding `Project.id` and `Keys.name` settings? Should I avoid uppercase? Also based on your advice in #2 to put all settings inside .settings(), is it OK to place there parameters with more complex expr such as `blablaOptions ++= Seq(...)`

Comment: I am not sure any naming convention is preserved even between various SBT plugins... just keep things consistent. Or use some linting tools: scalastyle, scalafmt, wart remover and try to run them on your code. If something is valid Scala concern it is also a valid SBT concern. Using Seq for adding several options at once is widely used as far as I can tell.